# wxPython: Multiline Text within a StaticBox

Tags: wxpython

Learning my way through this stuff and could use some help.  I'm trying to have a wxStaticBox with a label and a multiline text box inside of it (almost like a log that the app will print to...)

Here's as far as I've been able to get:

```
self.sb_FoldersToScan = wx.StaticBox(panel, label="Folders to Scan:", size=(200,100))
boxSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sb_FoldersToScan, wx.VERTICAL)
boxSizer.Add(self.sb_FoldersToScan, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT)
multiText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1,"test",size=(200, 100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
multiText.SetInsertionPoint(0)
boxSizer.Add(multiText)
sizer.Add(boxSizer, pos=(1, 0), span=(1, 6), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT)
```

I've cobbled most of this off the internet -- not trying to do anything right now other than get the layout fixed...

The multiText box shows up directly underneath the StaticBox rather than inside of it?  Am I using the wrong control for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are adding the static box itself to the sizer. If you delete the

```
boxSizer.Add(self.sb_FoldersToScan, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT)
```

line, I suspect it'll work.

Comment: Perfect.  One day I'll figure this out.  Still not sure what I did wrong conceptually though.  Maybe I added sb_FoldersToScan to the sizer twice?

Comment: you implicitly added it in the constructor of wx.StaticBoxSizer. Or at least sort of - you don't want the sizer to manage the static box in the same way as it manages it's contents as the static box should go around the outside of the contents, so it get's treated as a bit of a special case.

Comment: Thanks again -- this site is awesome and you guys are incredibly fast. :)